# How to Rotate Image without library functions in C++?

Tags: image-processing

My friends 
I got assignment to rotate image without using any library function
So now i want to Know that which algorithm I should learn 
and how i start work on it 
i read image using opencv but the rotation should be without library function
if some know 
Help me

Comment: rotate around an arbitrary angle or just 90/180/270 degrees?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds a lot like homework... but the concept you should learn is that for every target pixel(x,y) you need to find a source pixel in the image(u,v). You need a linear transform from(x,y) to (u,v). For translation you need to expand (x,y) to (x,y,1) and use a 3x2 matrix. Loop through all x,y pixels, find u,v by multiplying x,y,1 with a matrix, fetch the image pixel at u,v and draw it at x,y.

Comment: Good advice - especially the part about looping through the *target pixels* and finding a nearby *source pixel*. When I first started in image processing many years ago I looped through the input image pixels working out where they would go in the ouutput image and to my horror, after 2 days of serious maths and programming, I had my rotated image but it was full of holes where no input pixel had mapped to those output pixels :-)

Comment: @MarkSetchell - That was my problem too when I started out!